# How to tell if a company or organization is truly standing against systemic racism?

Tags: racism

With the recent events surrounding the death of George Floyd and other people of color, I have seen several companies issuing statements condemning racism and the aforementioned events.

Just to cite three organizations, [Archinect](https://archinect.com/features/article/150200715/archinect-s-statement-on-racial-injustice), [PwC](https://www.pwc.com/gx/en/news-room/press-releases/2020/pwc-statement-on-racism-and-discrimination.html) and even [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/10/stack-overflows-stand-against-racism-blm/?cb=1) issued statements in support of movements such as Black Lives Matter:

**Archinect** excerpt:

> We at Archinect are sad and outraged over the acts of violence that have been perpetrated against Black and African American people, both recently and historically.
>
> It must be said: The violent and unjust deaths of George Floyd, Breonna Taylor, Ahmaud Arbery, and so many others at the hands of law enforcement and otherwise are a direct expression of the pervasive racial injustice that shapes and contributes to the everyday experiences of so many people in America.

**PwC** excerpt:

> At PwC, we do not tolerate racism, discrimination, or violence of any kind. We prioritise and value the diversity of our people and we’re committed to fostering a culture where everyone feels they belong and has equal access to opportunities. When we see instances of racism or other forms of discrimination, wherever they may be, we all need to speak up and take action.

**Stack Overflow** excerpt:

> We must work together to end systemic racism. We stand in solidarity with our Black employees and with the Black community. Black lives matter. In this post, I am sharing some next steps that Stack Overflow is taking in order to leverage our place as an indispensable tool to the tech community in order to enact positive change.

I am sure that many companies publishing statements such as the ones above have the best of intentions and do want to facilitate change, but there will inevitably be skepticism about the motive of some organizations that put out sympathetic statements, either because of politics or simply just for fear that not doing so may be construed as silent endorsement for racism.

In other words, there will be organizations that will probably only pay lip service to the idea of opposing racial discrimination.

What are telltale signs that one can look for to determine whether an organization is truly standing against systemic racism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a politics question, but my advice would be to look for actions, especially those that come at a potential cost to the organization, not just words:

- Donating money is a start, and the simplest and most universal thing an organization can do.
- Depending on the company, even symbolic actions can be significant.

  - For example, [NASCAR banning the Confederate flag](https://www.nascar.com/news-media/2020/06/10/nascar-statement-on-confederate-flag/) is a pretty small step, but it's a real, significant action that, because of the politics of many of their fans, could come at a cost to the organization, and they should get some credit for (finally) being willing to take that step.
- A company can make internal changes to promote diversity so that the company's management better reflects the diversity of the community they serve. [Reddit appointing an African American member to their board of directors](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/10/21285835/reddit-board-replacement-alexis-ohanian-michael-seibel-y-combinator) is an example of this, though Alexis Ohanian should get most/all of the credit for that.
- More significant would be changing their business practices to stop supporting discrimination, despite the potential cost to the company. Some examples:

  - [IBM's decision to stopped selling facial recognition systems to police](https://www.npr.org/2020/06/09/873298837/ibm-abandons-facial-recognition-products-condemns-racially-biased-surveillance)
  - [drug companies refusing to make or sell drugs for lethal injection](https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/the-end-of-the-open-market-for-lethal-injection-drugs)